# Matrix Implementation in Python

Tags: python, matrix, complex-numbers

I am trying to implement a Matrix of Complex numbers in Python. But I am stuck at a particular point in the program.  I have two modules **Matrix.py, Complex.py** and one test program test.py. The module implementation is hosted in Github at https://github.com/Soumya1234/Math_Repository/tree/dev_branch and my **test.py** is given below

```
from Matrix import *
from Complex import *

C_init = Complex(2, 0)
print C_init
m1 = Matrix(2, 2, C_init)
m1.print_matrix()
C2= Complex(3, 3)
m1.addValue(1, 1, C2)//This is where all values of the matrix are getting 
                       changed. But I want only the (1,1)th value to be changed to C2
m1.print_matrix()
```

As mentioned in the comment, the addValue(self,i,j) in Matrix.py is supposed to change the value at the (i,j)th position only. Then why the entire matrix is getting replaced? what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not refer to external code in questions (it will get them closed), instead post a minimal working example here.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to implicitly make copies of `init_value` you could also change `Matrix.addValue` to this:

```
def addValue(self,i,j,value):
    self.matrix_list[i][j] = value
```

This is a little more in line with how your Matrix currently works. It's important to remember that a `Complex` object can't implicitly make a copy of itself, so `matrix_list` actually has a lot of identical objects (pointers to one object in memory) so if you modify the object in-place, it will change everywhere.

Another tip - try to use the `__init__` of `Complex` meaningfully. You could change this kind of thing:

```
def __sub__(self,complex_object):
    difference=Complex(0,0)
    difference.real=self.real-complex_object.real
    difference.imag=self.imag-complex_object.imag       
    return difference
```

To this:

```
def __sub__(self, other):
    return Complex(self.real - other.real,
                   self.imag - other.imag)
```

Which is more concise, doesn't use temporary initialisations or variables, and I find more readable. It might also benefit you to add some kind of `.copy()` method to `Complex`, which returns a new `Complex` object with the same values.

On your methods for string representation - I'd recommend displaying the real and imaginary values as `float`s, not integers, because they should be real numbers. Here I've rounded them to 2 decimal places:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "%.2f+j%.2f" %(self.real,self.imag)
```

Note also that you actually shouldn't need `__str__` if it should do the same thing as `__repr__`. Also, `show` seems to be doing roughly the same, again.

Also, in Python, there are no private variables, so instead of `getReal` it's entirely possible to just access it by `.real`. If you really need getter/setter methods look into `@property`.

As you're already doing some overloading, I would also recommend implementing `addValue` in `__getitem__`, which I think is a good fit of index setting under Python's data model. If you do this:

```
def __setitem__(self, inds, value):
    i, j = inds
    self.matrix_list[i][j] = value
```

You could change the `addValue` in `test.py` to this:

```
m1[1, 1] = C2
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that in your matrix initialization method you add the same value `C_init` to all entries of your matrix. As you are not just setting its value in each of the entries but the item itself, you get a huge problem afterwards: as the item stored in (0,0) is the same object as in all other entries, you change all entries together when you just want to change one entry.

You have to modify your initialization method like this:

```
  def __init__(self,x,y,init_value):
    self.row=x
    self.column=y
    self.matrix_list=[[Complex(init_value.getReal(), init_value.getComplex()) for i in range(y)] for j in range(x)]
```

In this way you add entries of the same value to your matrix, but its not every time a reference to the same object.

Furthermore: just for practicing this is a good example, but if you want to use the `Matrix` class yo compute something, you should rather use `numpy arrays`.

Comment: Thank you very much